# How to set multiple arguments for views contextual filters from twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

Am using twig tweak module to render views from Twig file. I have pass multiple values for the country contextual filter in the view. I was able to pass single parameter like:

```
{{ drupal_view('our_services', 'services',  countryTermId) }}
```

Not sure how to pass multiple values here:

```
{{ drupal_view('our_services', 'services',  countryTermId+globalId) }}
```

This is not working.

Comment: try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or if you need contextual filters with OR logic, and than just print it like  `{{ drupal_view('our_services', 'services',  countryTermId, globalId ) }}`

Comment: did you try with `{{ drupal_view('our_services', 'services', 'countryTermId+globalId' ) }}` the condition between **'** ?

Comment: ... this should be the most straightforward solution, but you have to concatenate the string with the  ~  operator: `countryTermId ~ '+' ~ globalId`

Comment: Thanks. This code is working for me..

Answer (score 3):

To pass contextual filters with OR logic, you can make use of the [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) module:

> The module provides a views plugin to modify query of contextual filters.
>   The module can changes contextual filters condition to OR logic.

When you install and enable the module from **Query settings** in your display check ***Contextual filters OR*** option and save:
[image]

Than in your twig:

```
{{ drupal_view('our_services', 'services', countryTermId, globalId ) }}
```

Comment: I have only one contextual filter enabled. I have to pass multiple values to it.

Comment: Did you try with Views Contextual Filters OR i don't see any way to do it without it, because `drupal_view` call `views_embed_view` and this not handle or, if you pass to it for example `12+10` it will pass it as `12`

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the [Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/twig-tweak-and-views), you can pass multiple variables like this:

`{{ drupal_view('who_s_new', 'block_1', arg_1, arg_2, arg_3) }}`